# OneDrive "remembers" accounts not used/signed-in on new MacBook

Tags: macos, microsoft-office, onedrive, privacy

**My Issue**

I have been struggling find a solution to this for about a week and need some help. I have recently bought a personal MacBook as dev machine for my research, so all it will have installed is a programming IDE, Git/GitHub, OneDrive (and not the rest of office) that is associated with my university account. The first thing I have installed is OneDrive (not from the App Store; just the standalone app from the Microsoft website), however once installed and on the sign-in page, I noticed that it is recommending me to sign-in with 2 other email accounts I have never used on this machine in a drop-down list. There is no way to remove them which is also infuriating because it will sometimes try to login with one of these other account which causes issues.

This concerns me since I have no clue as to how OneDrive could have access/knowledge of these other email accounts since this is a new machine not purchased or managed through my work/university. I haven't signed in anywhere else using them. The email associated with the Apple ID used on the laptop is different from that of the email accounts in the drop-down of OneDrive login screen. I do have access to the other email accounts that are in the drop-down menu though, so this isn't a massively serious issue; however it still brings me concern and headache.

**What I Have Done**

- After uninstalling the app, before reinstalling it I have checked that there are no residual files left on the Macintosh HD that are from Microsoft. I have ensured this in finder by searching for terms "Microsoft", "OneDrive" in the search bar, and allowing System Files to be checked as well, so files with names like **com.microsoft.<something_else>** and **com.microsoft.OneDrive.<something_else>** are all deleted.
- I have ensured that there are no keychains on this Mac that OneDrive could access to present to me on the sign-in screen that reference these extra email addresses.
- I have run the **ResetOneDriveAppStandalone.command** in OneDrive's Contents > Resources folder. This sadly has not removed the emails.
- I use these other emails on the Outlook app on my iPhone, however signing out of these accounts on my phone and removing them did not remove them from the OneDrive drop-down.
- I have also checked on each account that this MacBook is not listed as a device associated with the account.

**My Question**:

How could OneDrive possibly have known about these other emails and how can I remove them as login drop-down items?

**Edit**: These other emails accounts are mine, but haven't been used on this computer.

Comment: These emails are yours or someone’s email? [Edit] your question instead of submitting a comment

Comment: Are/were these accounts signed into any Microsoft app on another computer you have used the Apple ID you're signed into this computer? As in, why are you assuming the issue is with some secret sauce OneDrive data, and not with Apple trying to be helpful by recognizing you on a new device and suggesting some login credentials you may want to use again?

Answer (score 0):

**(Partial) Solution**

I have managed to find a solution to remove one of the unwanted emails. Running **RemoveOneDriveCreds.command** in OneDrive < Contents < Resources folder, I was able to locate the keychains that were generated for the different accounts. Deleting them removed one of the accounts however one of the others still remain.